# How to update document key in mongodb using update command?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nodejs-stream

I tried to insert data into mongodb.its sucessfully inserted but I facing issue wrong document insert into mongodb.how to update both key and value in document using update query in mongodb.

Json Data format

```
{
             "brand": "LG",
             "colour": "Black",
             "item height": "14 Millimeters",
             "item width": "14.1 Centimeters",
             "item weight": "200 g",
             "product dimensions": "13.5 x 14.1 x 1.4 cm",
             "item model number": "GP65NB60",
             "included components": "Power2Go, PowerBackup, YouCam, LabelPrint and Norton internet security (60 days trial)"
}
```

How to update key ex brand to brands using update query in mongodb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator to update the key as

```
db.collectionName.update( { _id: 1 }, { $rename: { 'brand': 'brands'} } )
```

and to update the values, use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator,

```
db.collectionName.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set:
      {
        key1: value1,
        key2: value2,
        .....
      }
   }
)
```